# how do you call a url in javascript or var codes

Tags: javascript, url, window

I have a little script written that displays a photo and clickable url on screen when the filename is called, but i would like to automatically have this url open up in a new window as well after the FILENAME is inputted or called on screen.
Can someone help?  My code for the calling of my file(inside an already setup window that is on screen) is below.

```
 var IO = {
"filename" : "<br />Filename <br />----------------------------------<br />some text here.<br /><br /><img src='http://myurl.com/aphoto.jpg' /><br /><a href='http://myurl.com/afile.html' target='_blank'>http://myurl.com/afile.html</a><br /><br />",
"help": "<br /><br />Available commands:<br />1. FILENAME<br />",
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable or some function that can get the url. Then, you can just execute `window.open(urlVariable)`

```
var link = "http://google.com";
var newWindow = window.open(link);
```

`window.open()` also has other parameters that can be passed: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open